# How to display a moving point on a path (on the map) in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am using the gyroscope and accelerometer sensors to find the coordinates of a moving object. After calculating these coordinates; I want to display these coordinates as a moving point on a path using MATLAB; as the object moves. The moving path should be display on a picture (map). kindly help me. Thanks!

Comment: Muhammad; your question is quite broad and as such is likely to be closed. You might want to show what you have tried so far to solve your problem and describe where you are stuck. Thanks!

Comment: I have calculated the coordinates using the accelerometer and gyroscope sensors and after this; 1st I want to import these coordinates from Arduino Microcontroller to MATLAB. kindly help me how to import these coordinates from arduino to MATLAB.

Comment: Secondly I want to display these coordinates on the map(a Picture), as a moving point; as the object moves. kindly help me how to display the coordinates as a moving point on a picture (map). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Easy.

This is just a fairly basic example, but from here, you can figure it out how to use MATLAB for drawing orbits, both from embedded systems or from batch data. In this example, a pseudo-chaotic lissajous orbit, plus a little brownian motion is shown as example.

Please note the `Update Plot` and the `Performance Options` under the `Main Cycle`, which do *all* the trick.

Please also note, the post indicate, you already estimated the coordinates :)...

```
% Set General Options
arduino_life=1;
figure;
n=50;
ts=0.01;
x0=10;
y0=0;
t0=now*24*3600;
% Define Plot
x=x0*ones(n,1);
y=y0*ones(n,1);
plot(x,y,'.');
title('Pseudo Chaotic Motion');
xlabel('X Dimension');
ylabel('Y Dimension');
axis([-20 20 -20 20]);
axis square;
% Execute Main Cycle
while(arduino_life)
    % Get Embedded Data
    ti=now*24*3600;
    xi=10*sin(2*pi*0.5*ti)*sin(2*pi*0.1*ti)+(ti-t0)*sin(ti)+0.5*randn;
    yi=10*cos(2*pi*0.5*ti)*cos(2*pi*0.1*ti)+0.5*randn;
    pause(ts);
    % Update Plot
    x=[xi;x(1:n-1,1)]; 
    y=[yi;y(1:n-1,1)];
    signal=get(gca,'Children');
    signal.XData=x;
    signal.YData=y;
    % Performance Options
    set(gcf,'doublebuffer','on');
    drawnow;
end
```

[image]

The orbit can be customized in any way. Lets that as proposed job :).